# Manga about this guy who was given a lightning weapon by this girl, and together they go fishing, and by fishing I mean they kill sea monsters?

Tags: story-identification, manga

From what I remember in the very first chapter, the guy and girl meet because the guy was lying on the ground, dying of hunger. Then the guy suddenly gets up and rips the girls clothes off as if to assault her. But he was only pretending to assault her; he mumbles that he wanted to get caught so that he could go to jail, because at least in jail he could get three meals a day.

The girl feels sorry for him and touches his hand to comfort him. Electricity sparks out when their hands touch and the girl decides to go fishing with him. Except instead of fishing for normal fish, these were gigantic sea monsters that could only be killed by a special weapon which produces lightning/electricity or something. The girl had this weapon, which belonged to her dead/missing brother, and she gave it to the guy, because he was compatible with it.

Monsters are killed and there are rewards for killing them. So the guy and girl share the money and eat, then go off and kill more monsters so they could keep getting money for food or something.

The only other thing I can remember about this manga is that this small octopus/squid touched the girl inappropriately, so in the next panel the octopus was dead and cooked and being eaten.

Comment: That is an excellent start! If you would, please visit [this link](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question?noredirect=1&lq=1) and see if you can [edit] in a few more details to help us help you.